# Adding smooth scrolling to bootstrap 4.1 (While using scrollspy)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So what i'm trying to do over here is to use the bootstrap 4.1s scrollspy function in my navbar. I've managed to get that to work. However I would also like to add smooth scrolling to it. After searching over the whole internet I still haven't managed to fix it.

Here's the original code that i am working with (same as from bootstrap).

```
<nav id="navbar-example2" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#fat">@fat</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#mdo">@mdo</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#one">one</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#two">two</a>
        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#three">three</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example2" data-offset="0">
  <h4 id="fat">@fat</h4>
  <p>...</p>
  <h4 id="mdo">@mdo</h4>
  <p>...</p>
  <h4 id="one">one</h4>
  <p>...</p>
  <h4 id="two">two</h4>
  <p>...</p>
  <h4 id="three">three</h4>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

And here's what i've tried to add to enable smooth scrolling.

```
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-item").click(function() {
        var t = $(this).attr("href");
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(t).offset().top - 50
        }, {
            duration: 1e3,

        });

        $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example2',offset: $(t).offset().top });
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');





        return false;
    });

});



//navbar
var distance = $('#site-header').offset().top,
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
        $('#site-header').addClass('fixed-nav')
    }
    if ( $window.scrollTop() <= distance ) {
        $('#site-header').removeClass('fixed-nav')
    }
});


$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example2',offset: 0 });
        </script>
```

As of now I feel stuck and I don't understand what it is i am doing wrong. Because I can't make it work. I've also tried adding different variations of css:s but I can't make it work. Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the jQuery selector for the click handler to...

```
$(".nav-link,.dropdown-item").click(function() {
  ...
});
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/y0LweX2FBY

The problem with the `nav-link` selector is that it doesn't have an href so the click handler isn't doing anything. Also, you probably want the Navbar `fixed-top` so that it doesn't scroll away when navigating to a section.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!! This was really helpful. However now I got a new problem, once i set the navbar to fixed and deleted the dropdown meny and added some content below the navbar. It doesn't seem to work.. I'm gonna try to fix it unless you have any magical tips once again!